# Resolving {src} constant does not work

Tags: inno-setup

I see that this question already was asked years ago, but without getting a reasonable answer.

Why doesn't this work with `{src}\some.exe` ?

```
// Launch Notepad and wait for it to terminate
// if Exec(ExpandConstant({win}\notepad.exe), '', '', SW_SHOW,
// ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode) then
```

If I copy notepad.exe into my Inno Setup directory, (`{src}\notepad.exe`) it does not work.
What is the secret on `{src}`?

Comment: I don't know what this question is about, but if `//` indicates a comment line in the config file, and if this is copied directly from your config file, have you commented out the instruction to use `{src}\notepad.exe`?

Comment: It is not that difficult. All I would like to know is why {win}\notepad.exe works and {src}\notepad.exe doesn't ...

Comment: 1) That code is nonnsense. As Jack wrote, `//` is comment. And `ExpandConstant({win}\notepad.exe)` won't compile, you are missing quotes. So please start by posting a working code.

Comment: 2) If the question was asked already, it's a good practice to link the existing answer.

Answer (score 0):

The `notepad.exe` does not work, if you copy it out of the `C:\Windows` folder. So that's a wrong binary to test the code against.

In general, there's no secret about the `{src}` constant. The code just works. But not with the `notepad.exe`.